# Express middleware - add promise rejection handlers

Tags: node.js, express, express-4

I have the following simplified middleware function:

```
router.put('/', function (req, res, next) {

  const data = req.body;
  const q = req.parsedFilterParam;
  const opts = req.parsedQueryOpts;

  ResponseCtrl.update(q, data, opts)
  .then(stdPromiseResp(res))
  .catch(next);
});
```

I want to add some ability to catch errors to the middleware, just to save some code, something like this:

```
router.put('/', function (req, res, next) {

  const data = req.body;
  const q = req.parsedFilterParam;
  const opts = req.parsedQueryOpts;

  return ResponseCtrl.update(q, data, opts)
  .then(stdPromiseResp(res));

});
```

so we now return the promise in the middleware function, and we can forgo the catch block.

so internally, it might look like this now:

```
nextMiddlewareFn(req,res,next);
```

just looking to change it to:

```
const v = nextMiddlewareFn(req,res,next);
if(v && typeof v.catch === 'function'){
   v.catch(next);
});
```

does anyone know how to do this with Express?

Comment: I suppose we could just switch to Koa, that might solve it. But simply using async/await probably won't solve it, or will it?

Comment: Doing what I was looking for in the question is not that safe. It's much safer if all middleware is only called after promise resolution.

Comment: this ended up working for me: https://medium.com/@the1mills/hacking-express-to-support-returned-promises-in-middleware-9487251ca124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [express promise router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router).

```
var router = new ExpressPromiseRouter();

router.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
  return somethingPromisey();
});
// or...
router.get('/bar', async function(req, res) {
  await somethingPromisey();
});

app.use(router);
```

PS: [There's no need to be afraid of `async`/`await` on performance grounds.](https://kyrylkov.com/2017/04/25/native-promises-async-functions-nodejs-8-performance/)  There is no appreciable difference vs regular functions with promises.

Comment: Promises are significantly less performant than vanilla callbacks. But you might be right that async/await is not less performant than promises.

Comment: That is correct; callbacks are definitely faster, but if you're already using promises, there's no additional penalty for `async`/`await`.

Comment: Accepted the answer, although as an aside I do suspect using generators does increase memory requirements even more than just promises, have to look into it more

Comment: you might enjoy this solution lulz https://medium.com/@the1mills/hacking-express-to-support-returned-promises-in-middleware-9487251ca124

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try the general purpose solution: [asyncback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asyncback).

For usage in ExpressJS middle-ware:

```
const asyncback = require('asyncback');
 
app.get('/users', asyncback(async (req, res) => {
    const users = await User.find({ 'banned': false });
    const offer = await Offers.findOne({ 'active': true });
    res.json({ 'users': users, 'offer': offer });
}));
```

When the async function returns or throws, the `next` callback passed by express to asyncback is automatically called accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Note to the reader, the following actually doesn't work:

```
router.put('/', async function (req, res, next) {

  const data = req.body;
  const q = req.parsedFilterParam;
  const opts = req.parsedQueryOpts;

  await ResponseCtrl.update(q, data, opts)
  .then(stdPromiseResp(res));

});
```

if the promise is rejected, the try/catch that surrounds each piece of middleware won't actually pick it up, if the promise is rejected, it will bubble up to an unhandledRejection handler if there is one.

*I would look forward to a good solution though which:*

1. could be typed with TypeScript
2. doesn't use async/await.

This is the solution that worked best for me as of now:

https://medium.com/@the1mills/hacking-express-to-support-returned-promises-in-middleware-9487251ca124

Comment: for a simple proof of concept, see: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/7debd0d057ee65306524739e2e74a1cf

Comment: I would be surprised if this actually works.  [The `try`/`catch` that express wraps around router handler calls is inside a regular function.](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.16.3/lib/router/layer.js#L86-L99)  `try` only catches rejected promises if you `await` them; in the express `try` block, the returned promise is completely ignored.

Comment: it's literally the same thing as your answer Josh, and my answer came first

Comment: No, `express.Router` does not support promises.  You have to use a module that adds promise support, which is what my answer suggests.

Comment: @josh3736 you're right, I was using domains on my server and that was catching the error, not the try/catch, I just got confused about why it was being trapped